# Verbatim description list item

Tags: lists, verbatim, description

How do I make an item in a description list verbatim? `\verb` in `\item[]` seems to be not allowed:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\verb+list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]+] bla bla bla
\end{description}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The package [`examplep`](http://ctan.org/pkg/examplep) provides several commands and environments for typesetting verbatim text. For instance, the robust commands `\PVerb[options]{text}`and `\Q{text}` can be used in macro arguments and in section titles as well.

Code example for your description list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Q=yes]{examplep}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[\Q{list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]}] bla bla bla
    \item[\PVerb{testing: \verb||{} #_$ }] item text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: verbatim example]

See [Verbatim phrases and listings in LaTeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/examplep/eurotex_2005_examplep.pdf) by Péter Szabó (or `texdoc examplep`) for further information. Escaping special characters (for instance with `\Q`) may be necessary as described in section 3.1 of the documentation.

Note, T1 font encoding has to be use to get a proper < symbol because it's unavailable in standard OT1 encoding.

Comment: Great answer, `\Q` works well for me, although I am not sure what the difference between that and `\PVerb` ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, the code in this answer works in TexLive 2019, if I remember correctly it works in TexLive 2020, but I see it just failed in TexLive 2021, with some error like `! Package examplep Error: \PVerb inner delimiter must be brace,
(examplep)                not backslash or control sequence or active char.`

Comment: I post a new question here about this issue: [examplep package used in description list item error under TexLive 2021](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628041/examplep-package-used-in-description-list-item-error-under-texlive-2021)

Answer (score 8):

The `\verb` command is not allowed inside arguments of other commands. One workaround is to use `\SaveVerb` from [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb).

The following definition of `\vitem` is taken from the *Companion*. It has an optional argument taking styling parameters from the `fancyvrb` package.

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newcommand\vitem[1][]{\SaveVerb[%
    aftersave={\item[\textnormal{\UseVerb[#1]{vsave}}]}]{vsave}}

\begin{description}
    \vitem+list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]+ bla bla bla
\end{description}
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion, a solution using `\cprotect`, and a solution that avoids `\verb` entirely.

Also (most of the time) answers the question: *How can I put verbatim inside an optional argument?*

```
\usepackage{cprotect}

...

\begin{description}
    \cprotect[o]\item[\verb+list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]+] bla bla bla
    \item[\textnormal{\texttt{list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]}}] bla bla bla
\end{description}
```

Without the `\textnormal`, the text produced by `\texttt` will be bold, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `cprotect` package is newer than when the question was posted.

Comment: And I can't find a duplicate.