# item formatting in description list

Tags: lists, description

How can I get this to work:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{foo :: a \rightarrow b}] bla
\end{description}
```

without having to write:

```
\begin{description}
    \item\ttfamily[foo~::~a~$\rightarrow$~b]\normalfont~bla
\end{description}
```

?

- \ttfamily: for typewriter formating
- ~: to get the spacing right(??)
- $: to activate math mode
- \normalfont: to get back to normal
- last ~: insert simple space(??)

or how would you list some function definitions and append a description for the functions?

Comment: Clear duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/verbatim-description-list-item

Comment: @frabjous: no, the other question is about `\verb`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{foo :: a $\rightarrow$ b}] bla
\end{description}
```

That is: add a closing brace and `$`s around `\rightarrow`.

Or maybe you want

```
\begin{description}
    \item[\texttt{[foo ::~a $\rightarrow$ b]}] bla
\end{description}
```

Comment: arg, sorry. I was fiddling around with item formatting all day long I started to believe you can't use formatting in item[] at all... Should I delete the question?

Comment: I don’t see a reason to do so.

Answer (score 12):

In this case I would `\usepackage{enumitem}`

And then write:

```
\begin{description}[font=\tt]
    \item[foo :: a $\rightarrow$ b] bla
\end{description}
```

This way you don't need to define the font for each of your items.

Answer (score 2):

i notice you're missing a closing brace before the closing bracket, other than that the two seem to produce identical output for me, save the enclosing brackets in your second example.