# How to include verbatim in a figure caption?

Tags: floats, captions, verbatim

I would like to include verbatim in a caption of a figure. I only want part of it to be verbatim, not the entire caption. The simple approach does not work because verbatim is not allowed in arguments of other commands, as [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/verbatim-description-list-item/2250#2250) explains. I tried using `\SaveVerb` and `\UseVerb`, but this does not work either. Is there a way to achieve this?

The code I used was the following:

```
\SaveVerb{term}|test|
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a \UseVerb{term}.}
\end{figure}
```

This did not compile (I will update the error message when I get home, don't have access to it right now). However, I already fixed this, as I explain in [my own answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8810/how-to-include-verbatim-in-a-figure-caption/8812#8812) to this question.

Comment: What do you mean, “does not work either”? `\SaveVerb` *definitely* works here. What exact code are you using and what error are you getting?

Comment: @Konrad I added the code that reproduced the error for me.

Comment: thanks for the code, and also for posting your solution.

Comment: \[Same question as [How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block) so I flag -- however since this one is older it's also okay to close the other way. Vote count is the same though]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, the simple solution was to use `\protect` before `\UseVerb`:

```
\SaveVerb{term}|test|
\begin{figure}
\caption{This is a \protect\UseVerb{term}.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: If used you need to place `\SaveVerb` before the list of figures.

Answer (score 28):

A new package `cprotect`(released no more than 2 weeks ago), solve this problem prefectly. And it is much easier to use.

```
\usepackage{cprotect}

\cprotect\caption{blah \verb|#$%^&| blah...}
```

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/cprotect.html

There are still several other solutions. As is referred, `\SaveVerb` and `\UseVerb` from `fancyvrb` is also useful. And you can even do it mannually all by yourself:

```
% in preamble
\newsavebox\verbbox
% in document env.
\begin{lrbox}{\verbbox}
\verb|@#$%#%|
\end{lrbox}
\caption{\usebox{\verbbox}}
```

Comment: thanks. You also need to "protect" the figure environment containing the caption using `\cprotEnv`. --- A point to note is that optional arguments are not yet supported by `\cprotect`. They will be in the next release (soon).

Comment: @Burno: Thanks for your comment, your new package is very useful. In `figure` env, `\cprotect\caption` does works for me, without `\cprotEnv\begin{figure}`. I'm not sure when to use `\cprotEnv`.

Comment: The documentation is not good, I have to admit. And you are right about the `\cprotEnv` being useful only in some border cases: basically, each time the environment is not a true environment, i.e., gobbles its argument before doing something with it. A typical example is the `align` environment (although `\cprotEnv` does not seem to play well with that), and every environment define using the `environ` package. Not many applications, but it was my initial motivation (for a private package), so I left it.

Comment: `\cprotect` made `\verb|`...`|` work great, but now I have `^^E^^L` on the end of my caption (`\cprotect` makes it appear whether I use `\verb` or not).  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BenVoigt This should probably a new question on the main site.

Answer (score 18):

Everything can also be done with `\texttt`, not so short as with verb, but it is possible. A backslash is `\textbackslash`.

Comment: Indeed. Sometimes it's a bit awesome, however. One must use `\texttt{a\symbol{95}b}` to get `a_b` correctly, `\texttt{a\\_b}` is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I finally decided to go with it, as it actually fits my intend better (I just want some special identifiers to stand out from the text). The advantage of using `\texttt` is that it also wraps.

Comment: @LeoLiu `\texttt{a\_b}` works fine for me...

Comment: @GerhardBurger how convenient when you have 4 or 5 `_` in the word...