# How can I have inline code (delimited by |) in a footnote or in a caption?

Tags: errors, listings, inline

I've defined `|` as a "short inline character", using

```
\lstMakeShortInline|
```

I'd like to use that delimiter to typeset inline code in a footnote or a caption, e.g.

```
\footnote{Java uses the |break| keyword...}.
```

However, upon compilation, I get the following error:

```
Argument of \lst@temp has an extra }.
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I did not get any error running this  \footnote{Java uses the |break| keyword...}. I could not understand what you are trying to do with inline listing. I thought you want to create in line list like 1.a 2.b 3.c etc in footnote. can you clarify more

Comment: @Aku: he is using the `listings` package. It works like verbatim but it also "highlights" the code according to the some programming language dependent rules.

Comment: Please add a complete (with preamble) [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footnotes, by default, cannot contain "naked" verbatim content. However, loading the `bigfoot` package, for instance, will allow you to use a single-character shorthand for inline listings (such as `|`) in footnotes without any problem.

Typesetting an inline listing in a caption using a single-character shorthand is more difficult; see, for instance, [verb inside lstlisting caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71247/verb-inside-lstlisting-caption). You're probably better off using `\lstinline` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=Java]|
\newcommand\inlineJava[2][]{\lstinline[language=Java,#1]+#2+}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
... some table ...
\caption{\inlineJava{break}}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-3]

Here is some tidbit about |break| but that's not the whole story.%
\footnote{Java uses the |break| keyword.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
a\footnote{Java uses the \lstinline|break| keyword.}
\end{document}
```

Works. If you're trying to do something different, please update your question with a minimal example as Caramdir suggested.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to include verbatim in a figure caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8810/how-to-include-verbatim-in-a-figure-caption)

Comment: That works for verbatim, actually, the `fancyvrb` package.  The question is about `listings`, which does more than verbatim.  According to the `listings` manual, the `listings` package provides some sort of interface to the `fancyvrb` package, maybe that could be used.  However, I really do not understand that part of the manual. It is not clear to me what is the interface supposed to do, and how would one go about using it.