# verb inside lstlisting caption

Tags: listings, verbatim

I try to do this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Perl,caption={text {\verb+myverb+} some more text}]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

But it gives me something like:

```
Undefined control sequence ... some more
```

How to I include an linline `verb` inside my caption?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need `\verb` because what you denote with `myverb` has special characters in it? If it hasn't, then `\texttt{myverb}` does the same.

Comment: Okay, that works and looks the same. I would really prefer to use verb if possible at all, because I like to `grep` through my tex files and I now won't collect all `verb`s with this. But that is a minor setback. If there is no real solution, please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\verb` is a very peculiar command in LaTeX and this peculiarity consists in the fact that it may not appear in the argument of another command. In your example it is in the optional argument to `\begin{lstlisting}` and this is disallowed (because of *very* good reasons).

Actually `\verb` is necessary only when characters special for (La)TeX are needed: `# $ % ^ & { } _ \`. When none of these character is needed, one can use `\texttt{myverb material}` with the same result as that given by `\verb`.

However, this doesn't solve the problem of grepping through your files for finding all `\verb`. You can do

```
\protected\def\psverb#1{\def\innerpsverb##1#1{\texttt{##1}}
```

and the example would become

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\protected\def\psverb#1{\def\innerpsverb##1#1{\texttt{##1}}\innerpsverb}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Perl,caption={text {\psverb+myverb+} some more text}]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Grepping for `\verb` *or* `\psverb` should be quite easy.

Comment: Perfect solution and thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `{\psverb!S#Var!}`: `You can't use 'macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.` I have to escape hash characters, like so now compared to `Verb!...!`: `{\psverb!S\#Var!}`

Comment: @EmitTaste Yes, that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 4):

Another option not requiring any new commands is to use `\lstinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Perl,caption={text {\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily]+myverb+} some more text}]
...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my new `cprotectinside` package:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cprotectinside}

\begin{document}
\cprotectinside{*}{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Perl,caption={text *\verb+myverb+* some more text}]
code code
code code
\end{lstlisting}
}
\end{document}
```

<sub>(this answer is also included in the package documentation as an example)</sub>