# How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block?

Tags: errors, verbatim, bold

It looks like you can't use `\verb|...|` inside of `\textbf{...}`. I tried the following:

```
\textbf{Be very careful when using \verb|-i| as it's destructive and it's not reversible!}
```

And got this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: More generally, you can't use `\verb` inside any other command's argument (apart from some commands which are specially made to support this, by not really using an argument here).

Comment: There are some alternatives [fancyvrb, verbdef, fvextra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33113/verb-in-custom-command/33132#33132),

Answer (score 24):

It depends on what you want the verbatim to support. If you simply want to put some normal text in "verbatim" (typewriter) font, then use `\texttt`. If you want to allow special characters such as `_`, `&`, or `^` to be displayed as is, then `\listinline` (which xport mentions) may be enough, and allows to customize the font somewhat.

However, `#` or `%` will still give you trouble if you don't somehow tell the surrounding command that they are there: for instance, as soon as `%` is *read* from the file the first time, TeX ignores the rest of the line, and there is no way to retrieve it. Here you will have two options that I know of: either save the offending piece of verbatim text prior to using it, for instance with `newverb`, or tell the surrounding command to first read its argument verbatim, via the `cprotect` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
Try \cprotect\textbf{this \verb|%ther #pt\on|}.
\end{document}
```

Actually, in the case of `\textbf` and other font commands, you can also use the corresponding switch, `\bfseries`, as in `{\bfseries this \verb|%&#| example}`.

Answer (score 16):

Use `listings` package, it is very useful and can be used everywhere, either in section heading or body.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\lstset
{
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\tt\color{red},
}
\begin{document}
\section{This is an inline listing in \lstinline|section|}
Remember \lstinline|I can find| a tool to convert PDF to EPS
\lstinline!in my! neither bathroom nor kitchen.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Here does `lstset` defined for all `\lstinline`s?

Answer (score 14):

use `\texttt` instead and a monotype font which supports a bold typeface. `\verb` cannot be inside another macro.

Answer (score 1):

I made a package to handle this case. Use it like this

```latex
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotectinside}
\begin{document}

\cprotectinside{!}{\textbf{using !\verb|-i|! as} ...}

\end{document}
```

Its main advantage is that it can handle the protected content arbitrarily deeply nested. e.g. in those cases it can be a little difficult to figure out what to cprotect.

- [verb inside lstlisting caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71247/verb-inside-lstlisting-caption)
- [How to use verbatim in figure caption (\captionof)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117743/how-to-use-verbatim-in-figure-caption-captionof)

It's on CTAN now with documentation, but if there's any bug source code can be found in https://github.com/user202729/TeXlib

Basically the syntax is `\cprotectinside{ <delimiting character> }{ <text> }`, where the region between 2 consecutive delimiting characters occurring in the text will be c-protected.

Comment: Another example, although this one is not-that-difficult https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/649703/250119

Comment: Temporary note: some environments such as `tabularx` applies some "hack" on `\verb` which breaks it even with `\cprotectinside`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/671310/how-to-typeset-a-regular-expression-string-in-a-latex-table?noredirect=1&lq=1