# \verb in custom command

Tags: macros, verbatim

I have `\newcommand\dd[2]{\item[\texttt{#1}] #2}` and later I have

```
\dd{bc}{text \verb#$(echo 5+4 | bc)# text \verb#$((5+4))# text}
```

and I get

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
<argument> ...nicht mit \verb ##$(echo 5+4 | bc)##
rechnen, sondern die neue...
l.74 ...ekten Rechnen, \verb#$((5+4))#, benutzen.}
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.
```

How can I get the verbatim into my command without the command interpreting it wrongly?

Comment: You can't use verbatim inside a macro argument in general, because the whole argument will then already be parsed before `\verb` does its thing. Therefore `#` is still the normal macro argument character which can't be used on its own here.

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin

Comment: The best thing to do is to define `\dd` with *one* argument, that is, `\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\item[\texttt{#1}]}`; then `\dd{bc} text \verb#$(echo 5+4 | bc)# text \verb#$((5+4))# text` will work as you wish.

Comment: This question is a special case of [listings - How to define macro that only makes argument substitution? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/how-to-define-macro-that-only-makes-argument-substitution/622711#622711) where there's a *simpler solution* because the verbatim command being used (`\verb`) can be replaced with `\texttt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but I think the simplest solution may be something along the following model. Note that one has to "escape" the dollar sign by prefixing a backslash to it; on the other hand, it's not necessary to introduce verbatim strings explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dd[2]{\item[\texttt{#1}] #2}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\dd{bc}{text \texttt{\$(echo 5+4 $|$ bc)} text \texttt{\$((5+4))} text}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in comment, `verbatim` or its short form `\verb` is a different beast altogether. If you *must* pass `verbatim` stuff as arguments, you could consider a [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) work-around.

Using `fancyvrb` you can save and restore your `verbatim` commands in the following way:

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\DefineShortVerb{\#}% # denotes verbatim opening/closing character
\SaveVerb{VerbA}#(echo 5+4 | bc)#
\SaveVerb{VerbB}#$((5+4))#
```

This stores `(echo 5+4 | bc)` as-is in `VerbA`, and `$((5+4))` in `VerbB`, which can be used (restored) later by means of `\UseVerb{VerbA}` and `\UseVerb{VerbB}` respectively. Here is a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newcommand\dd[2]{\item[\texttt{#1}] #2}
\begin{document}
\DefineShortVerb{\#}% # denotes verbatim opening/closing character
\SaveVerb{VerbA}#(echo 5+4 | bc)#
\SaveVerb{VerbB}#$((5+4))#
\begin{description}
  \dd{bc}{text \UseVerb{VerbA} text \UseVerb{VerbB} text}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit**: A similar work-around exist using the [`verbdef` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/verbdef). It provides `\verbdef{<cmd>}{<verb>}` that defines `\<cmd>` with verbatim `<verb>` content. The following MWE produces the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbdef}
\newcommand\dd[2]{\item[\texttt{#1}] #2}
\begin{document}
\verbdef\VerbA{(echo 5+4 | bc)}
\verbdef\VerbB{$((5+4))}
\begin{description}
  \dd{bc}{text \VerbA\ text \VerbB\ text}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would prefer `\verbdef` from the `verbdef` package.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Great simplification. I've added it as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays you can use the more "robust" `\Verb` from [`fvextra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fvextra) package.

Note both `\Verb|...|` and `\Verb{...}` is supported (with some restrictions). Also when used as argument, don't use `#` as delimiters.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}
\newcommand\dd[2]{\item[\texttt{#1}] #2}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \dd{bc}{text \Verb{$(echo 5+4 | bc)} text \Verb{$((5+4))} text}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
\newcommand\dd[2]{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}} #2}
```

This will print #1 vermbatim.