# How to create a minimal working example for verbatim use in macro definition with cprotect?

Tags: macros, verbatim

[cprotect](http://ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) can be used to use `verbatim` in a macro definition according to the package specification. Just like everything else in the world that doesn't provide an example it doesn't work in real life and therefore I want/have to do that job myself. Why does

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\bla}{Like this one: \verb-!@#$%^&*()_+-.}
% same in TeX
%\def\bla{\verb+Yes!+}
\cprotect\bla
\end{document}
```

not work (error message is `! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \@argdef.`? Using a `verbatim` environment doesn't work (or does, we'll see...).

Comment: It isn't really fair to say there isn't enough documentation, because basically the whole source code is documented; what you want is a brief overview how it works (so you can deduce what it does in unexpected cases). See [*my* answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/622512/250119)  for that, or [*my* other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622711/250119) for a solution that allows arguments in the replacement text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\cprotect\bla` allows to have `\verb` in the argument to `\bla`, but since `\bla` has no argument, nothing is done.

You have to `\cprotect` the *definition* of `\bla`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\cprotect{\newcommand{\bla}}{Like this one: \verb-!@#$%^&*()_+-.}

\bla
\end{document}
```

See the trick explained at the end of section 1 in the manual.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! The formulation "just write \cprotect\cs or \cprotect{\cs} instead of \cs" is ridiculous and even with the prepending half sentence "if you want {<arg1> } to contain verbatim". It upsets me when so much brilliance and effort is put into the package and then documentation basically abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Using my new `cprotectinside` package.

Declare the "special delimiter character" to be `/`, then use it to wrap around the verbatim-like commands (`\verb`). Read the documentation for more details.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cprotectinside}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\cprotectinside{/}{
    \newcommand{\bla}{Like this one: /\verb-!@#$%^&*()_+-./}
}
\bla
\end{document}
```