# Using \input inside environment fails

Tags: listings, input, filecontents

I'm trying to use the `filecontents` package in combination with `listings` as suggested in [How to define macro that only makes argument substitution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42144/how-to-define-macro-that-only-makes-argument-substitution) in order to produce a side-by-side view of LaTeX code and the corresponding output.

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,filecontents}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \csname filecontents*\endcsname{\jobname.tmp}}{%
  \csname endfilecontents*\endcsname
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \input{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
}%

\begin{testenv}
Some lines?
of text !!!
here.
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Actual result:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \openin 
l.1 Some lines?
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I copied this part from somewhere, but I think it's because the body of a `filecontents*` environment is treated as verbatim text, and then normal rules don't apply.

Comment: The `verbatim` content is indeed a problem here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find `\tcbverbatimwrite` from `tcolorbox` very convenient. It has support for `listings` as well and can be configured in multiple ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}



\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \begingroup%
  \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.tmp}}%
{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \input{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{testenv}
Some lines?
of text !!!
here.
\end{testenv}

\end{document}
```

**Improved version**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}



\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \begingroup%
  \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.tmp}}%
{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup%
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \input{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
    \lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily]{\jobname.tmp}%
  \end{minipage}%
}


\newenvironment{othertestenv}{%
  \begingroup%
  \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.tmp}}%
{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup%
  \noindent
  \tcbinputlisting{colback=white!30!yellow,text side listing,listing options={basicstyle=\ttfamily},listing file=\jobname.tmp}%
}

\begin{testenv}
Some lines?
of text !!!
here.
\end{testenv}

\begin{othertestenv}
Some lines?
of text !!!
here.
\end{othertestenv}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So with `tcolorbox` you only need

```
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

...

\newtcblisting{testenv}{%
  colback=white,text side listing,boxrule=0pt,opacityframe=0}
```

and that's it!

```
\begin{testenv}
Some lines?
of \emph{text} !!!
here.
\end{testenv}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Yes, that would be a simpler version then