# lstlisting and newcommand conflict

Tags: macros, listings

I would like to make a document that displays figures and the corresponding code, and want to cut down on repeating myself.  MWE below.  I think there is something wonky about lstlisting in a newcommand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}


\newcommand{\figMe}[3]{
\begin{figure}
#3
\caption{#2. See Listing~\ref{lst#1} for code.}
\label{fig#1}
\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={#2. See Figure~\ref{fig#1}.},label={lst#1}]
#3
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}


\figMe{ex1}{Example drawing}{
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the answers. This is what I ended up doing, using external files...

```
\newcommand{\figMeToo}[3]{
\begin{figure}
\input{#3}
\caption{#2 See Listing~\ref{lst#1} for code.}
\label{fig#1}
\end{figure}%\FloatBarrier
\lstinputlisting[frame=tb,caption={#2 See Figure~\ref{fig#1}.},label={lst#1},captionpos=b,language={[latex]TeX}]{#3}%\FloatBarrier
}
```

Comment: you can't use any verb-like commands in such a definition. the listings package documents specific new commands to define new environments based on listings

Comment: Have a look at `tcblisting` from the tcolorbox package if you want to show both the latex input and result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd written some code in the past for myself (one of my documentations), that allowed me to decouple input and output as far as I needed myself. The code in this answer reuses much of that code, but there are likely some dead keys in these definitions that won't work for you because I created them for my own output.

I removed some of the keys, but I might've overlooked one or the other. The `gappend`, `no-append`, and `after` keys are all functional, but you'd have to build something on your own with them (I created `gappend` to be able to store away some code and add it later on to the output of another environment, but since your code only ever has a 1:1 correspondence that isn't too useful for you, I guess).

This implementation of `enverb` will ignore the first *n* characters of each line of its body, where *n* is the number of whitespaces before the matching `\end` (so here `\end{figMe}`) plus the number specified for the `more-ignore` key (2 in this example -- which is the amount of indentation I personally use in my documents). My own documents don't use `<Tab>` but only spaces, I have no idea how well tabs work with this (let's say it should work, but is not extensively tested).

These are many lines of implementation (well, it's a package draft, so just pretend everything in between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is hidden behind `\usepackage{enverb}`), the code I used for your output is really just the 26 lines of code:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{figMe}{mm}
  {\enverb} % enverb will collet an additional o-arg for its own options
  {%
    \enverbUnexpandedOutput
      {\begin{figure}}% pre-contents
      {% post-contents
        \caption
          {%
            #2. See Listing~\ref{lst#1} for code.%
            \label{fig#1}%
          }%
        \end{figure}%
      }%
    \enverbExpandedOutput
      {% pre-contents
        % we don't want to expand the begin part
        \unexpanded
          {%
            \begin{lstlisting}
              [caption={#2. See Figure~\ref{fig#1}.},label={lst#1}]%
          }%
      }
      % verbatim output in lstlistings needs to see the \end as a string without
      % a trailing space
      {\string\end{lstlisting}}% post-contents
  }
```

The entire document with the `enverb` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \enverb@count \tl_count:n
\cs_set:Npx \enverb@othercr { \char_generate:nn {13} {12} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
%% key setup
\ekvdefinekeys{enverb}
  {
     boolTF  auto-ignore   = \enverb@ifautoignore
    ,initial auto-ignore
    ,protected code ignore = \let\enverb@ifautoignore\@secondoftwo
    ,also eint      ignore = \enverb@ignore
    ,eint    more-ignore   = \enverb@moreignore
    ,initial more-ignore   = 2
    ,long store bol = \enverb@bol@content
    ,long store eol = \enverb@eol@content
    ,einitial   eol = \enverb@othercr
    ,data gappend   = \enverb@append
    ,code no-append = \let\enverb@append\@secondoftwo
    ,store after    = \enverb@after
  }
\protected\long\ekvsetdef\enverbsetup{enverb}

%% auxiliary error function
\newcommand\enverb@error[1]
  {%
    \GenericError
      {(enverb)\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces}%
      {Environment enverb error: #1}%
      {Just use it correctly!}%
      {Read the sources.}%
  }

%% setup for weird category code regime
\begingroup
\lccode`\~=`\^^M
\catcode`\:=13
\lccode`\:=`\ % <- space
\catcode`\;=13
\lccode`\;=`\^^I % <- tab
\lowercase{\endgroup
%% code for spaces and CR
\def\enverb@body@space{}%
\def\enverb@body@tab{}%
\def\enverb@body@newline#1~%
  {\enverb@ifnotend{#1}{\enverb@bol\unexpanded{#1}\enverb@eol~}}%
%% activate the category code regime of the body
\protected\def\enverb@body@setup
  {%
    \let\enverb@collected@body\@empty
    \let\do\@makeother\dospecials
    \catcode`\^^M=13 \let~\enverb@body@newline
    \catcode`\   =13 \let:\enverb@body@space
    \catcode`\^^I=13 \let;\enverb@body@tab
    \let\enverb@bol\relax
    \let\enverb@eol\relax
  }
%% check for optional argument
\newcommand\enverb@search@oarg@a
  {%
    \ifx:\next
      \ifenverb@firsteol
      \else
        \enverb@body@add{:}%
      \fi
      \let\next\enverb@search@oarg@b
    \else
      \ifx~\next
        \ifenverb@firsteol
          \enverb@firsteolfalse
        \else
          \enverb@body@add{~}%
        \fi
        \let\next\enverb@search@oarg@b
      \else
        \ifx[\next\@gobble]%
          \let\next\enverb@oarg
        \else
          \ifenverb@firsteol
            \let\next\enverb@body@after@begin
          \else
            \let\next\enverb@body
          \fi
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \next
  }
%% start body collection
\newcommand\enverb@body
  {\edef\enverb@collected@body{\iffalse}\fi\expandafter~\enverb@collected@body}
%% check the line after an oarg
\def\enverb@body@after@oarg#1~%
  {\enverb@ensure@blank{#1}{closing bracket}\enverb@body}
%% check the line after the \begin statement
\def\enverb@body@after@begin#1~%
  {\enverb@ensure@blank{#1}{\string\begin}\enverb@body}
}
%% quick check for empty line
\newcommand\enverb@ensure@blank[2]
  {%
    \expandafter\enverb@ifempty\expanded{{#1}}{}%
      {%
        \expanded{%
        \noexpand\enverb@error
          {%
            Line after #2 not empty.\noexpand\MessageBreak
            Contains: \detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral`\^^@#1}%
          }%
        }%
      }%
  }
%% quick check for empty argument
\newcommand\enverb@ifempty[1]
  {%
    \enverb@ifempty@\enverb@ifempty@A#1\enverb@ifempty@B.\enverb@ifempty@true
      \enverb@ifempty@A\enverb@ifempty@B
  }
\def\enverb@ifempty@#1\enverb@ifempty@A\enverb@ifempty@B#2#3{#3}
\def\enverb@ifempty@true\enverb@ifempty@A\enverb@ifempty@B#1#2{#1}
\newcommand\enverb@gadd[2]{\xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1#2}}}
\newcommand\enverb@body@add[1]
  {%
    \edef\enverb@collected@body
      {\unexpanded\expandafter{\enverb@collected@body#1}}%
  }
% start of environment `enverb'
\newcommand\enverb
  {%
    \begingroup
      \def\tmp{enverb}%
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\enverb@ifnotend@setup@perhaps\expanded
      {{\string{\@currenvir\string}}}%
    \begingroup
    \enverb@body@setup
    \enverb@firsteoltrue
    \let\enverb@collected@oarg\@empty
    \enverb@search@oarg
  }
\newif\ifenverb@firsteol
\newcommand\enverb@search@oarg{\futurelet\next\enverb@search@oarg@a}
\newcommand\enverb@search@oarg@b{\expandafter\enverb@search@oarg\@gobble}
\newcommand\enverb@oarg{\endgroup\enverb@oarg@}
\NewDocumentCommand\enverb@oarg@{O{}}
  {%
    \edef\enverb@collected@oarg{\unexpanded{#1}}%
    \begingroup
    \enverb@body@setup
    \enverb@body@after@oarg
  }
\def\enverb@ifnotend#1%
  {%
    \def\enverb@ifnotend##1%
      {%
        \enverb@ifnotend@
          ##1\enverb@mark\enverb@ifnotend@maybe
          #1\enverb@mark\@thirdofthree
          \enverb@stop
      }%
    \def\enverb@ifnotend@##1#1##2\enverb@mark##3##4\enverb@stop{##3{##1}{##2}}%
  }
\expandafter\enverb@ifnotend\expanded{{\expandafter\@gobble\string\\end}}
\newcommand\enverb@ifnotend@maybe[2]
  {\expandafter\enverb@ifnotend@perhaps\expandafter{\romannumeral`\^^@#2}{#1}}
\newcommand\enverb@ifnotend@setup@perhaps[1]
  {%
    \def\enverb@ifnotend@perhaps##1%
      {%
        \enverb@ifnotend@perhaps@\enverb@mark##1\enverb@mark\enverb@ifnotend@end
          \enverb@mark#1\enverb@mark\@thirdofthree
          \enverb@stop
      }%
    \def\enverb@ifnotend@perhaps@
        ##1\enverb@mark#1##2\enverb@mark##3##4\enverb@stop
      {##3{##2}}%
  }
\providecommand\@thirdofthree[3]{#3}
\newcommand\enverb@ifnotend@end[3]
  {%
    \iffalse{\fi}%
    \enverb@ensure@blank{#1}{\string\end}%
    \expanded
      {%
        \endgroup
        \enverbsetup
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\enverb@collected@oarg}}%
        \noexpand\enverb@final
          {\unexpanded\expandafter{\enverb@collected@body}}%
      }%
      {#2}%
    \expandafter\end\expandafter{\@currenvir}%
  }
\long\def\enverb@final#1#2%
  {%
    \enverb@ifautoignore
      {\enverb@setup@ignore{\enverb@count{#2}+\enverb@moreignore}}%
      {\enverb@setup@ignore\enverb@ignore}%
    \edef\enverb@line##1\enverb@eol
      {%
        \noexpand\detokenize{##1}%
        \noexpand\unexpanded{\unexpanded\expandafter{\enverb@eol@content}}%
      }%
    \edef\enverb@collected@body{#1}%
    \expanded
      {\unexpanded{\enverb@append\enverb@gadd\@gobble}\expandafter}%
      \expandafter{\enverb@collected@body}%
  }
\providecommand\@firstofnine[9]{#1}
\newcommand\enverb@setup@ignore[1]
  {\expandafter\enverb@setup@ignore@\the\numexpr#1\relax;\enverb@line}
\def\enverb@setup@ignore@#1;#2%
  {%
    \ifnum#1>9
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    {\expandafter\enverb@setup@ignore@\the\numexpr#1-8;{\@firstofnine{#2}}}%
    {%
      \let\enverb@bol@gobble\@empty % just so that renewcommand doesn't go nuts
      \expanded
        {%
          \unexpanded{\renewcommand\enverb@bol@gobble}\ifnum#1>\z@[#1]\fi
            {\unexpanded{#2}}%
          \unexpanded{\def\enverb@bol##1\enverb@eol}%
            {%
              \noexpand\unexpanded
                {\unexpanded\expandafter{\enverb@bol@content}}%
              \unexpanded{\expandafter\enverb@ifempty\expanded}{{##1}}%
                {\noexpand\enverb@line}%
                {\noexpand\enverb@bol@gobble}%
              ##1\unexpanded{\enverb@eol}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
  }
% the output routine if you'd use only an `enverb` environment, empty for you
\let\endenverb\@empty
\NewDocumentCommand\enverbExpandedOutput{O{} +m +m}
  {%
    \begingroup
      \everyeof{\noexpand}%
      #1\relax
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \scantokens\expanded
      {{%
        #2\enverb@othercr
        \enverb@collected@body
        #3\enverb@othercr
      }}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\enverbUnexpandedOutput{O{} +m +m}
  {%
    \begingroup
      \everyeof{\noexpand}%
      \newlinechar=\endlinechar
      #1\relax
      \expandafter
    \endgroup
    \scantokens\expanded
      {{%
        \unexpanded{#2}%
        \enverb@collected@body
        \unexpanded{#3}%
      }}%
  }
\makeatother


\NewDocumentEnvironment{figMe}{mm}
  {\enverb} % enverb will collet an additional o-arg for its own options
  {%
    \enverbUnexpandedOutput
      {\begin{figure}}
      {%
        \caption
          {%
            #2. See Listing~\ref{lst#1} for code.%
            \label{fig#1}%
          }%
        \end{figure}%
      }%
    \enverbExpandedOutput
      {%
        % we don't want to expand the begin part
        \unexpanded
          {%
            \begin{lstlisting}%
              [caption={#2. See Figure~\ref{fig#1}.},label={lst#1}]%
          }%
      }
      % verbatim output in lstlistings needs to see the \end as a string without
      % a trailing space
      {\string\end{lstlisting}}%
  }

\begin{document}
  \begin{figMe}{ex1}{Example drawing}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \end{figMe}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Ulrich Diez's `DefineVerbatimToScantokens` macro (can be found in a few answers, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/626166/250119) as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mwe}



%=== Code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens ========================
% With older LaTeX-releases uncomment the following line:
%\usepackage{xparse}   
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineVerbatimToScantokens{mm}{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12\relax
  \InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{#1}{#2}%
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{mm+v}{%
    \endgroup\ReplaceHashloop{##3}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
  \newcommand\ReplaceHashloop[3]{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\Hashcheck##1#1}$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \NewDocumentCommand{##2}{##3}{%
         \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar
         \scantokens{\endgroup##1#2}%
      }%
    }{%
      \expandafter\ReplaceHashloop\expandafter{\Hashreplace##1}{##2}{##3}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\Hashcheck{\long\def\Hashcheck##1#1{}}%
  \@ifdefinable\Hashreplace{\long\def\Hashreplace##1#1{##1####}}%
}%
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\catcode`\#=12\relax
\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{#}{%}%
%=== End of code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens =================




\DefineVerbatimToScantokens{\figMe}{m m +v}{
\begin{figure}
#3
\caption{#2. See Listing~\ref{lst#1} for code.}
\label{fig#1}
\end{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={#2. See Figure~\ref{fig#1}.},label={lst#1}]
#3
\end{lstlisting}
}

\begin{document}


\figMe{ex1}{Example drawing}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\end{document}
```

Although using `{...}` to delimit verbatim environment is a bit fragile in my opinion that comments must be `{}`-brace-balanced.