# \verb in command does not work

Tags: luatex

I have some options to typeset
a command line option
with a comment inside

```
\verb|-interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2 -s outputtemplate="%j.mps"|
```

Because I need in many places
(in fact there are other reasons),
I use a command instead:

```
\newcommand{\metapostOptions}{\verb|-interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2-s outputtemplate="%j.mps"|}
```

There is a reason, complicated to explain, which prevents me from just escaping the percent like so: `\%`; in fact the text in the command is generated.

I can define the command only if i include this in change of catcode.

```
\catcode`\%=12
\newcommand{\metapostOptions}{\verb|-interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2-s outputtemplate="%j.mps"|}
\catcode`\%=14
```

Still I cannot use, because then

```
(./test.out) (./test-1.cpt

! LaTeX Error: \verb ended by end of line.
```

I really don't understand what happens and cannot help myself.

Help very much appreciated.

Comment: you used `\verb` with `{` which is wrong `\verb{-i...` but you can not use `\verb` in the argument of any command

Comment: `I can define the command only if i include this in change of catcode.` no that avoids the errr but verb does not work in that context, just use `\texttt`

Comment: I adapted my question. I have a reason that I cannot just escape the %.. I should have told before, sorry. 
I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: While you *can* use `\verbdef` in `newverbs` package, you may want to consider the alternative of modifying the "generator" to output `\%` instead of `%` in the first place. There are other alternatives such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/626166/250119

Comment: @user202729 I used the first suggestion. I have no access on the converter.

Comment: @David: also a solution. catcode inside newcommand.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that, but most catcode changes in a new comnand will not do anything useful

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own macro that reads in the replacement text in a verbatim way and store that in `\metapostOptions`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand \newverbcontent { m v }
  {\newcommand#1{\texttt{#2}}}

\newverbcontent\metapostOptions
  |-interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2-s outputtemplate="%j.mps"|

\begin{document}
Use the following command line options: \metapostOptions.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `\verb` in the argument of a command.

Use

```
\newcommand{\metapostOptions}{%
 \textt{-interaction=nonstopmode -recorder -s prologues=2-s outputtemplate="\%j.mps"}}
```

Comment: @ David: I adapted my question: THere is a reason so that i cannot escape the percent explicitly. 
I found that I can use with cprotect.. but.. does not work either..

Comment: @user2609605 then use `\texttt` and use `%` by changing catcode as you show  in the question

Comment: yes, change catcode withint the macro replacement section.