# Why does verb throw an error using in multicolumn command?

Tags: tables, verbatim

I encounter an error when using the `\verb` command within the `multicolumn` command. I reduced the problem to the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\verb+test+} 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Error message: `\verb illegal in command argument`

**1. Why is using `\verb` not allowed within `\multicolumn` ?**

**2. How can I workaround this issue ?**

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I believe that this question covers your problem (especially the answer by **xport**): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block Some more information is in answer by **Werner** here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33113/verb-in-custom-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the package [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb), I hope that the following example is self-explanatory (With credit to **Werner**):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb
\begin{document}
\DefineShortVerb{\#}% # denotes verbatim opening/closing character
\SaveVerb{VerbA}#test#

\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
Row 1 & Row 1 \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\UseVerb{VerbA}} \\
Row 3 & Row 3
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

The reasoning why you cannot use `\verb` in macro argument is a bit more complicated. As an argument, the `\verb|test|` is 1st read+stored in memory, and 2nd processed. While the command `\verb` needs to be proceesed at the same time as its read, basically because it has to remember the delimiter (`|` or `#` or whatever) and only then it can read the argument `test`.

*(In real, it is more complicated and has to do with TeX inner mechanism of reading and interpreting its input, I only tried to give a short overview.)*

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the solution !