# LaTeX Source Code Listing Horizontally In Figure With Subfloats

Tags: listings, subfloats

I'm trying to embed a couple of `listings`

```
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> from sympy import Integral, latex
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> latex(x**2)
x^{2}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
>>> from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
>>> from sympy import Integral, latex
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> print mathml(x**2)
<apply><power/><ci>x</ci><cn>2</cn></apply>
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> fcode(sqrt(1-x**2))
'      sqrt(-x**2 + 1)'
\end{lstlisting}
```

as a figure with images subfloated as shown [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats).

Is there an easy way (least amount of LaTeX code) for me to do that?

Comment: A simple way would be to put them in a `minipage`, assuming that they can all fit next to each other

Comment: Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34946/how-can-i-put-lstlisting-block-into-subfloat-block/34949#34949

Comment: Are you sure you want all three listings in one single row? Do you want the result to be treated as a floating object?

Comment: Good Point. Just testing the waters with LaTeX and what I could do with it. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The listings you gave are quite wide and won't fit horizontally next to each other. But, for a case where they will fit next to each other, you can put each in a `minipage`.  This will put each listing next to each other.

[image]

To make this float just place it within a `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> abc
>>> def
>>> ghi
x^{2}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> jkl
>>> mno
>>> pqr
>>> stu
vwx
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
>>> 123
>>> 456
>>> 789
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also post these vertically, since they are very wide.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
%\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{varwidth}% http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing A}]
>>> from sympy import Integral, latex
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> latex(x**2)
x^{2}
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{varwidth} \par
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing B}]
>>> from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
>>> from sympy import Integral, latex
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> print mathml(x**2)
<apply><power/><ci>x</ci><cn>2</cn></apply>
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{varwidth} \par
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Listing C}]
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> fcode(sqrt(1-x**2))
'      sqrt(-x**2 + 1)'
\end{lstlisting}
  \end{varwidth}
  \caption{A number of listings.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The choice of using [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) is merely to center the listings horizontally with respect to one another in the figure. Replacing `varwidth` with `minipage` will yield a flush left-aligned set of listings.