# Showing listings of code side by side error

Tags: errors, listings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I put lstlisting block into subfloat block?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34946/how-can-i-put-lstlisting-block-into-subfloat-block)

Running this code gives me an error that **! Paragraph ended before \lst@next was complete.**

```
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[subcaption 1]{

\begin{lstlisting}
text here
\end{lstlisting}

}
\hspace{80pt}

\subfloat[subcaption 2]{
\begin{lstlisting}
text here
\end{lstlisting}
}

\caption{Global caption}
\end{figure}
```

I want to display code side by side

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34946/how-can-i-put-lstlisting-block-into-subfloat-block/34949#34949

Comment: Well, I tried to put the code myself in a file by \lstinputlisting{filename} and it works but how can I specify that the filname code has C# code?

Comment: You can specify the language using `\lstset{language=[Sharp]C}`. See the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (p 11-12, section **2.4 Programming languages**). Note that some settings are possible via the optional argument to `\lstinputlisting`, but some are not and are best set via `\lstset`.