# How to share a counter for a subfloat

Tags: listings, numbering, subfloats

I am trying to make a listing float containing 3 subfloats. I have managed to to make the actual float by combining the answers from [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517926/latex-how-to-make-listings-subfloats-use-listing-counters-toc-etc) and [question2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34946/how-can-i-put-lstlisting-block-into-subfloat-block).

Now I only need to make mylisting use the same counter as listings so the three programs are named Program 1, Program 2 and Program 3.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{subfig}
\let\newfloat\undefined %for working with memoir

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
columns=flexible,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
showstringspaces=false,
tabsize=3,
numberbychapter=false,
frame=single,
extendedchars=true,
}

%% Declare mylisting
\DeclareNewFloatType{mylisting}{placement=htbp,fileext=lol,name=Program}
\floatsetup[mylisting]{style=Plaintop}

%% Rename "List of listings" to "Programmer"
\floatname{lstlisting}{Program}
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{ 
  \begingroup 
    \listof{lstlisting}{Programmer} 
  \endgroup 
}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{}

\begin{filecontents*}{dangling.hun}
if <expression> then
<statement>
if <expression> then
<statement>
<else>
<statement>
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting[caption={A program}]{dangling.hun}

\begin{mylisting}[htbp]
  \caption{These are my subfloats}
  \subfloat[First]{\begin{minipage}{0.28\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Second]{\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling1,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Third]{\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling2,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
\end{mylisting}

\lstinputlisting[caption={Another program}]{dangling.hun}



\end{document}
```

**Update**
I have sort of fixed it by using `calc` by making the following change. However, I'm interested in a cleaner way to do it.

```
\begin{mylisting}[htbp]
...
\end{mylisting}
```

to

```
\begin{mylisting}[htbp]
\setcounter{mylisting}{\value{lstlisting}}
\setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{mylisting}+1}
...
\end{mylisting}
```

Comment: It will be nice if you upvote the answers in addition to accepting them @Jonas Nyrup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're interested in making a slave duplicate counter to that of `listings` for your `mylisting` environment. For this you need to issue

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@mylisting\c@lstlisting}
\makeatother
```

This copies the contents of the `listings` counter `\c@lstlisting` into the contents of the `mylisting` counter `\c@mylisting`. As such, `\c@mylisting` will reference the same counter register as `\c@lstlisting` and therefore duplicate it's behaviour. The reason for issuing this `\AtBeginDocument`, is because `\let` copies its contents as-is at the time of issue. However, `listings` delays the creation of its counter until `\AtBeginDocument`; for reference, the following is taken from [`listings.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.dtx):

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifundefined{thechapter}{\let\lst@ifnumberbychapter\iffalse}{}
  \lst@ifnumberbychapter
      \newcounter{lstlisting}[chapter]
      \gdef\thelstlisting%
           {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \else
      \newcounter{lstlisting}
      \gdef\thelstlisting{\@arabic\c@lstlisting}
  \fi}
```

The above suggestion was taken from [Slave duplicate counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33898/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{subfig}
\let\newfloat\undefined %for working with memoir

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
columns=flexible,
basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
showstringspaces=false,
tabsize=3,
numberbychapter=false,
frame=single,
extendedchars=true,
}

%% Declare mylisting
\DeclareNewFloatType{mylisting}{placement=htbp,fileext=lol,name=Program}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\c@mylisting\c@lstlisting}
\makeatother
\floatsetup[mylisting]{style=Plaintop}

%% Rename "List of listings" to "Programmer"
\floatname{lstlisting}{Program}
\renewcommand{\lstlistoflistings}{ 
  \begingroup 
    \listof{lstlisting}{Programmer} 
  \endgroup 
}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\chapter{}

\begin{filecontents*}{dangling.hun}
if <expression> then
<statement>
if <expression> then
<statement>
<else>
<statement>
\end{filecontents*}

\lstinputlisting[caption={A program}]{dangling.hun}

\begin{mylisting}[htbp]
  \caption{These are my subfloats}
  \subfloat[First]{\begin{minipage}{0.28\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Second]{\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling1,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Third]{\begin{minipage}{0.32\linewidth}
\lstinputlisting[label=dangling2,nolol]{dangling.hun}\end{minipage}}
\end{mylisting}

\lstinputlisting[caption={Another program}]{dangling.hun}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome. It was `\AtBeginDocument` I was missing