# \verbatim environment compatible with lingmacros \enumsentence

Tags: verbatim, linguistics, lingmacros

Using the verbatim environment inside an \enumsentence fails.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\begin{document}
\enumsentence{
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

I can do a workaround using `\texttt{ }`, but then I have to escape a bunch
of funny characters and in general I'd prefer `verbatim` for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the characters you have to escape? Can you make a "real life" example?

Comment: in this example, i was working with many underscores,  I had used vim s/_/\\_/g and s/$/\\\\/ to put the underscores and explicit line breaks throughout.  But I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  `\cprotect` seems to work without issue for this.

Comment: Do you need typewriter type? Other special characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the package `cprotect`. Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\enumsentence{
\begin{verbatim}
foo
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

FYI, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/14) is where I found the answer to your question.