# How to use verbatim in figure caption (\captionof)?

Tags: floats, captions, verbatim

I want to use verbatim in a caption of a figure. I have tried the [`cprotect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) package but it seems to work only with `\caption` and not with `\captionof`. Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\verb|works|

\afterpage{%
    \begin{landscape}
      \parbox[c][\textwidth][s]{\linewidth}{%
        \vfill
        \centering
        \mbox{+++++++ a huge figure ++++++++}
        \captionof{figure}{Syntaxbaum \verb|doesn't works|}
        \vfill
      }
    \end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't suppose `\texttt{doesn't works}` would do the trick?

Comment: `\verb` is useful for material that includes TeX's special characters; if it's not the case, use `\texttt` and the result will be what's needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the verbatim environment.

Comment: This can also be solved by nesting `\cprotect` as mentioned in its documentation, or use my `cprotectinside` package (although the question is closed, and the target question can already be easily solved with `cprotect`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the verbbox before the figure and then recall it therein.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\verb|works|

\begin{verbbox}
now it works
\end{verbbox}
\afterpage{%
    \begin{landscape}
      \parbox[c][\textwidth][s]{\linewidth}{%
        \vfill
        \centering
        \mbox{+++++++ a huge figure ++++++++}
        \captionof{figure}{Syntaxbaum \theverbbox}
        \vfill
      }
    \end{landscape}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]