# How do i put verbatim text as the body of a link?

Tags: hyperref, verbatim

Is there a way i can have verbatim text inside a link?

`\href{www.numpy.org}{\verb|numpy|}` does not work. I tried using `cprotect`;

`\cprotect\href{www.numpy.org}{\verb|numpy|}`, but then I end up with `!TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you really need verbatim or is `\texttt{}` enough for you?

Comment: I'd try `\cprotect{\href{www.numpy.org}}{\verb|numpy|}`, but `\href{www.numpy.org}{\texttt{numpy}}` is much easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to put `\verb` command inside of `\textbf` block?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/5764) (different error message, but same cause/solution).

Comment: @Werner No, the OP already know about `\cprotect`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to brace `\href{www.numpy.org}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{\string\verb}: \cprotect{\href{http://www.numpy.org}}{\verb|numpy|}

With \texttt{\string\texttt}: \href{http://www.numpy.org}{\texttt{numpy}}

\end{document}
```

However, using `\cprotect` doesn't seem necessary here, as the example with `\texttt` shows.

Don't forget `http://` or the link won't work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works for me without the `http://` though, should it not?

Comment: @will This depends on features of the PDF viewer. It doesn't with Skim, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way using a `verbatimbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\numpy}n$_umpy\end{myverbbox}
And now we \href{www.numpy.org}{\numpy}\,.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A comment here to remind myself that within beamer, `\begin{myverbbox}` should be put *outside* of a `\begin{frame}{Title}` environment.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found after many hrs googling for an answer.  Nothing else I tried worked. Thanks.