# How to render a sharp sign that denotes the number of a set?

Tags: math-operators

In math, # usually denotes the number of elements in a set (cardinality).

For example, in this equation

[image]

the #D{x} operator denotes the number of elements in the set D that satisfies property x.

I am trying to render this character in TeX, and this code

```
$\#D$
```

gives this symbol:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Related: [How to write a nice # symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236792/how-to-write-a-nice-symbol)

Comment: @siracusa  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the font used in the image is Adobe Times/URW Nimbus as provided by the `txfonts` package (or some very similar variant of it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\[ \hat\thetaup_{ijk} = \hat P(X_i=x_{ij}\mid Y=y_k)
    = \frac{\#D\{X_i=x_{ij} \wedge Y=y_k\}}{\#D\{Y=y_k\}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

*Original answer*

The font used in your image is not the default Computer Modern font. You could use `\text{\ttfamily\#}`, which is closer to the symbol in the image, but still not the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\tthash{\text{\ttfamily\#}}

\begin{document}
$\#D$ vs. $\tthash D$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Wikipedia also just lists the standard `\#` as a [symbol for cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject#Cardinality).

For the exact same output, you need to find the font that provides this special hash character glyph.

Comment: `txfonts` has many weaknesses, avoid it and prefer `newtxtext,newtxmath`.