# Listings and verbatim-like environments in a tikz node using newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, listings

I have seen answers to this question floating around but none of them appeared to solve the problem.

I want to be able to throw a code block into an already defined `tikzpicture`. So I attempted to make a command that replaces `\node{};` and ran into a known problem with verbatim-like environments inside commands.

I have a complete example here.
It does not build with `pdflatex`.
Notice blue `\node` works, but `\rednode` fails.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\rednode}[1]{
   \node[draw=red]{#1};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}

   \node[draw=blue]{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   };

   \rednode{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Solutions explored involve the `cprotect` package, `tabular` environments, and `minipage` environments.

Comment: Somewhat special case of [errors - How to put \verb command inside of \textbf{} block? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24574/how-to-put-verb-command-inside-of-textbf-block), although `\verb`-specific options there does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Box the listing before using it in the argument for `\node`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\rednode}[1]{
   \node[draw=red]{#1};
}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=blue]{};
\rednode{\usebox\mybox}: 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

With this approach you don't need the `fragile` option for `frame`; I left it just in case you want to add some other non previously boxed verbatim material.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cprotect does work in this simple case. OP probably didn't use it correctly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\newcommand{\rednode}[1]{
   \node[draw=red]{#1};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}

   \node[draw=blue]{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   };

   \cprotect\rednode{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or use `\cMakeRobust`, as mentioned in the documentation of `cprotect` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{cprotect}

\newcommand{\rednode}[1]{
   \node[draw=red]{#1};
}
\cMakeRobust{\rednode}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{tikzpicture}

   \node[draw=blue]{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   };

   \rednode{
\begin{lstlisting}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
} 
\end{lstlisting}
   }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```