# How to make `\verb` valid inside starred version of sectioning commands?

Tags: verbatim, cprotect

It seems `\cprotect` does not make `\verb` valid inside *starred version* of sectioning commands, `\section*`, `\paragraph*` etc.

How to fix this problem?

```latex
% MWE
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect\part*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\chapter*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\section*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\subsection*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\subsubsection*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\paragraph*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect\subparagraph*{text and \verb"\verb"}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I also want to suggest using my cprotectinside package  (see answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640353/250119 ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\begin{document}
\cprotect{\part*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\chapter*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\section*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\subsection*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\subsubsection*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\paragraph*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\cprotect{\subparagraph*}{text and \verb"\verb"}
\end{document}
```