# How can I add 1 line of source code (source code snippet) in a LaTeX document?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sourcecode

The easiest way of explaining this is probably to provide an example of what I want to do:

Consider the following section of a LaTeX document.

```
Calls to the function
// a blank line
get_next_random_number(int) // This should be monospace (texttt) and centered on page
// another blank line
should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
```

So far I have this (LaTeX code):

```
Calls to \\\\\texttt{get_next_random_number(int)}\\\\should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
```

But I have no idea how to set this so it is centred on the screen rather than left-justified.

Comment: What you want to centre is not quite clear. The whole text? Only the text in monospaced font?

Comment: Only the monospaced bit - the line of source code.

Comment: Well, why not use the `center` environment?

Comment: @Bernard is this: \begin{center}....\end{center}?

Comment: Absolutely!  :–)

Comment: @Bernard Alright I'll try it. Seems like a very convoluted solution. Can I define a command to short-cut this for me?

Comment: @Bernard If you add that as a solution I'll accept it - I see that this method also adds the newlines for me automatically. Is there a solution for when I don't want a new line either side of my single centred line? I guess one never really wants to do this?

Comment: i'd be inclined to try the technique described in [How to include verbatim in a figure caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8810/579), but use it instead within `\[ \text{...} \]`.  (but haven't actually tried it; lack of time.)

Comment: You mean the centred thing is on its own line, but  with no vertical spacing added? There is the `\centerline{…}` command.

Comment: Take a look at the many packages for typesetting listings, (my favorite is listings). Not directly a solution to your request, though.

Answer (score 3):

Do you looking something like this?

[image]

**Edit:** 
document classes as `article`, `report`,and`bool` among many others contain facility for writing verbatim text, i.e. a text as it written by typewriter. It has two forms:

```
\begin{verbatim}
       text_which_will_appear_in_final_document_as_here
       (with "_" between words, which otherwise require
        to be written as "\_" ... 
\end{verbatim}
```

which people usually use for presenting some code (as it is in your case) or in short form for presenting this code in a text by `\verb{...}` or `\verb+...+` or any other pair of equal characters. Above image I obtain with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \begin{document}
Calls to
    \begin{center}
\verb+get_next_random_number(int)+
    \end{center}
should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
    \end{document}
```

This form I select since you ask how to write code in typewriter characters centered in the text. If you for exaple like to have this code for example four characters form left text border, you can write as

```
Calls to
\begin{verbatim}
    get_next_random_number(int)
\end{verbatim}
should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
```

For verbatim environments also exist specialized packages as `fancyvrb` and others, which enables more sophisticated writing of verbatim texts.

Comment: What is \verb? Is this specifically for source code? I notice it puts the tt type font in there automatically.

Comment: @user3728501, \verb/ is macro for typing a text as it is (shortens for verbatim). It is available in all basic LateX document class (`article`, `report`, `book`). For above example I use `article`.

Comment: @user3728501, I upgrade my answer with complete MWE as well with short explanation of `verbatim` environments. I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is use the `fancyvrb` package and the `BVerbatim` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document
Calls to the function
\begin{center}
\begin{BVerbatim}
get_next_random_number(int)
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}
should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Calls to 

\begin{center}\texttt{get_next_random_number(int)}\end{center}

should be independent of previous calls, resulting in a Fourier Space distribution with no eigenfrequency.
```

Comment: Don't leave blank lines around the `center` environment.