# Using \lstinline inside an \item in beamer class in case of incremental overlay specifications?

Tags: beamer, listings, description

The answers of [Using \lstinline inside a \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/93944/18401) work rather nicely with the `beamer` class.

But, as pointed out by the following MCEs when `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` is uncommented, they don't work if incremental overlay specifications are used: the item labels are not printed.

Is there a way to use `\lstinline` inside a `\item` in `beamer` class in case of incremental overlay specifications?

- [Martin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/93950/18401):

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}

  \usepackage{listings}

  \makeatletter
  \let\orig@item\item

  \def\item{%
      \@ifnextchar{[}%
          {\lstinline@item}%
          {\orig@item}%
  }

  \begingroup
  \catcode`\]=\active
  \gdef\lstinline@item[{%
      \setbox0\hbox\bgroup
          \catcode`\]=\active
          \let]\lstinline@item@end
  }
  \endgroup

  \def\lstinline@item@end{%
      \egroup
      \orig@item[\usebox0]%
  }
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Foo}
  The arguments of the function are:

  % \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
  \begin{description}
  \item[\lstinline!foo!]
      Name of the file \\[1cm] % other [ ] still work as normal!
      something
  \item[\lstinline!bar!]
  Permissions
  \item[\lstinline!%^$]_!]
  verbatim
  \end{description}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```
- [Elrond's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181325/18401):

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}

  \usepackage{listings}

  \newcommand*{\lstitem}[1]{
    \setbox0\hbox{\lstinline{#1}}
    \item[\usebox0]
  }

  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{Foo}
    The arguments of the function are:

    % \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
    \begin{description}
      \lstitem{foo}
      Name of the file
      \\[1cm] % other [ ] still work as normal!
      something
    \lstitem{bar}  Permissions
    \end{description}
  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: Can you post a complete MWE? Even with the contents of the linked posts, this doesn't seem to be complete. (Files are missing, I think, though I'm not certain how it is supposed to work exactly.)

Comment: @cfr Sorry, the MCEs based on Martin's and Elrond's answers were wrong indeed. That's fixed now.

Comment: Have a look at the explanation of what `fragile` does in Beamer's manual. I think that's where the impossibility of this lies.