# Use the nomencl and listing packages to include a command summary

Tags: listings, nomenclature, nomencl

I am writing a document related to computer science and I want to include a short summary of the commands that appear through the text at the end. I am using the listing package to handle the code and I want to use the nomencl package to create the summary, but when I try to add a new entry inside the `lstinline` environment, it does not appear in the nomenclature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{listings}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\section{section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\clearpage
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{\lstinline|test command|}{This is a test with a command}
\nomenclature{test}{This is a test without a command}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

The code produces the following output:

[image: document without the nomenclature entry]

As you can see the nomenclature entry inside `lstinline` does not appear. Is there a way of making this work or can you think of an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

For `\nomenclature` the `|` and `!` characters are reserved. You can use for example `\lstlinline?test?`. For the rest this question is a near-duplicate of [Using \lstinline inside a \item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93944/using-lstinline-inside-a-item) and the solution is also from there.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{listings}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=bash}
\section{section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\nomenclature{\lstinline?echo?}{This is a test with a command}
\nomenclature{test}{This is a test without a command}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@item\item

\def\item{%
    \@ifnextchar{[}%
        {\lstinline@item}%
        {\orig@item}%
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\]=\active
\gdef\lstinline@item[{%
    \setbox0\hbox\bgroup
        \catcode`\]=\active
        \let]\lstinline@item@end
}
\endgroup

\def\lstinline@item@end{%
    \egroup
    \orig@item[\usebox0]%
}

\makeatother

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]