# Put \lstinline inside \item[] description and automatically add \item[] content to a glossary

Tags: listings, glossaries, itemize, inline

I've implemented [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93944/using-lstinline-inside-a-item) solution to allow placing `\lstinline` code inside description `\item` command.
I also want to automatically add the entire `\item` content as a glossary entry by placing it into `name` field of `\newglossaryentry` command.
The `\item` content consists of text and `\lstinline` code.

Since the `\item` content is stored in a box register, when I try something like `name={\usebox0}` the entry name doesn't appear in the document glossary.
I think this is because `\usebox0` isn't being properly expanded in `.glsdefs` file (all entry names are stored literally as `\usebox 0`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Redefine \item command.
\makeatletter
\let\orig@item\item

\def\item{%
    \@ifnextchar{[}%
        {\lstinline@item}%  %@
        {\orig@item}%
}

\begingroup
\catcode`\]=\active
\gdef\lstinline@item[{%
    \setbox0\hbox\bgroup 
        \catcode`\]=\active
        \let]\lstinline@item@end
}
\endgroup

\def\lstinline@item@end{%
    \egroup
    \orig@item[\usebox0]%
    % Extra lines for adding entries to glossary.
    \stepcounter{mycount}%
    \newglossaryentry{\themycount}{name={\usebox0}, description={}}%
    \glsadd{\themycount}%
}
\makeatother

% Glossaries.
\usepackage[automake]{glossaries}
\glsnoexpandfields
\glssetexpandfield{name}
\makeglossaries
% Counter for glossary labels.
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}


\begin{document}


\printglossary[style=index]

\chapter{Some chapter}

Some text.

\begin{description}
\item[First] Description.
\item[Second] Description.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

I already know how to put `\lstinline` code in the `name` field without causing any error.
So I'm looking for some mechanism to store the `\item` content in a macro which can be expanded in the `name` field, as well as store it in the box register (which is already solved) to avoid the `\lstinline` inside `\item` problems.

I think could be something like `\def\storedContent{...}` but in the same way `\setbox0\hbox\bgroup...\egroup` works.
I don't know, I've tried many things without success, so any solution will be welcome.