# Put \lstinline inside \chapter, \section, etc. commands

Tags: sectioning, listings, titles, inline, arguments

How can I place `\lstinline` code inside commands like `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.?

Or it's a bad or tasteless practice?

Comment: It's not usually a good idea.  Why are you wanting to do that?

Comment: @Teepeemm: Same reasons listings is used in other places, highlight code from normal text. For example, a section could be named: Use of `while` keyword.

Comment: You can, just use `\protect\lstinline!...!` since the argument of the titles are moving and therefore fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, as long as you `\protect` moving arguments:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The \protect\lstinline!if! command}

\section{The \protect\lstinline!while! command}

\subsection[More commands]{The \lstinline!end! command}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have something more difficult [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620566/using-lstinline-inside-a-item-and-add-item-content-to-glossary) if you have time: place text with `\lstinline` code inside `\item` description AND automatically add the `\item` content to a `glossaries` entry.

Comment: Sorry @Werner, it almost works, only fails with the characters `%#&`, etc.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: It works when I use `\%` or `\#`.

Comment: I mean `%#&` simbols as code in `\lstinline`.

Comment: @AlbertoLópez: Me too. See [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/DDWm7FRP) that produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxmVc.png).

Comment: Ok, I just saw the error in my code, thanks.

Comment: I also see this kinds of error when I try to use `\lstinline|MOV A, #12H|` in the choice items of this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141643/24012, the result is that I see two `##` in the rendered output. Luckily, I find the answer here. I just try to use this `\protect\lstinline|MOV A, \#12H|`, and the problem is gone, I mean the rendered text is correct. But I see this is still a bit complex, any better solutions?  BTW, I think Werner's code mentioned here https://pastebin.com/raw/DDWm7FRP should be added to the answer.