# examplep package used in description list item error under TexLive 2021

Tags: verbatim, examplep

I used the `examplep` package in description list item, I just follow the answer by [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz) in his answer this question: [Verbatim description list item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/verbatim-description-list-item).

Here is the test code, which is exactly the answer in that question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[Q=yes]{examplep}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[\Q{list comprehension [f a | a <- M a]}] bla bla bla
    \item[\PVerb{testing: \verb||{} #_$ }] item text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

If I remember correctly, it works OK in my TexLive 2020 and before. But it looks like it failed in my new TexLive 2021(I'm using Windows 7 64bit OS, and the Xelatex is used), with such errors:

```
(e:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd
File: t1lmtt.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)

! Package examplep Error: \PVerb inner delimiter must be brace,
(examplep)                not backslash or control sequence or active char.

See the examplep package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7     \item[\PVerb{testing: \verb||{} #_$ }]
                                               item text
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
<argument> \PVerb {testing: \verb ||{} ##
                                         _$ }
l.7     \item[\PVerb{testing: \verb||{} #_$ }]
                                               item text
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7     \item[\PVerb{testing: \verb||{} #_$ }]
                                               item text
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: It works up to TeX Live 2018.

Comment: The documentation states “For new documents, only the use of `\PVerbOpt`, `\Q`, `÷` and `\÷` is recommended.”

Comment: Well, there are workarounds/other methods to achieve the same thing, depends on what exactly you want to do. If the documentation states that it's not supported you can't really do anything about it.

Comment: Hi, @egreg, thanks for the comment, I just change the `\PVerb` to `\Q`, it built without errors, but the generated pdf file dose not shown the verbatim text. I looked at the document of `examplep`, it is written in year 2004, so it suspect this document is too old.

Comment: @ollydbg23 As far as I can see, `\Pverb{x}` has been broken from the LaTeX release on 2020-02-02 (possibly a bit earlier). Almost two years without any intervention on the package can only mean that nobody's using it.

Comment: Hi, @egreg, thanks for the info. The whole picture is that I would like to put some verbatim text in the choices in my answer statement here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141643/24012  I used the `\PVerb{x}` in my choices, but I think I have to choose another way to do this. Do you have other suggestions. Maybe, I could try the `listing` package, and use the `\lstinline|x|` statement.  Or are there any better way? thanks.